# How to use HTML and PHP to create a multi-form search function with only one submit button?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

Following on from a recent post.

I am creating a search function that queries a SQL database. The database consists of different types of meat packaging. I have created HTML & PHP code that will search the database and display results using only one form and submit button. But I now want to create a search box that has multiple forms (including three dropdown ones), that when users type in sizes, click a dropdown and type in a id code, they can submit using one submit button and then will be referred to a page that consists of the results that match all three combined.

Can anyone give me some insight about how to go about this? I have tried creating two forms that submit to the same PHP page for results, but one seems to override the other.

*Here is my HTML and PHP code currently:*

```
    <body>

    <form action="form2.php" method="post"> 
              Search: <input type="text" name="term" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </form> 


</body>
```

*And the PHP code:*

```
   <body>


   <?php
    $con = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db ("delyn_db", $con);

  if (!$con)
    { 
    die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    }


$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);    

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM delyn WHERE toolcode LIKE '%".$term."%' OR trayheight LIKE
     '%".$term."%' OR delyncode LIKE '%".$term."%' OR description LIKE '%".$term."%' 
      OR trayshape LIKE '%".$term."%' OR traydepth LIKE '%".$term."%' OR traywidth
     LIKE '%".$term."%'";
     $r_query = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$sql)
    {
        echo "could not find";
    }

       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){ 
       echo 'ID: ' .$row['ID']; 
       echo '<br /> Delyn code: ' .$row['delyncode']; 
       echo '<br /> Tool Code: '.$row['toolcode'];
       echo '<br /> Description: '.$row['description']; 
       echo '<br /> Tray range '.$row['trayrange']; 
       echo '<br /> Tray type: '.$row['traytype'];
       echo '<br /> Tray size: '.$row['traysize']; 
       echo '<br /> Tray height: '.$row['trayheight']; 
       echo '<br /> Tray width: '.$row['traywidth']; 
       echo '<br /> Tray depth: '.$row['traydepth'];
       echo '<br /> Tray shape: '.$row['trayshape'];  
       echo '<br /> imagename: '.$row['imagename'];
       echo '<br /> Tray live: '.$row['traylive'] . ' <br /><br />';  
    }


?>

    </body>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Edited php:

```
  <body>

    <?php
$con = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db ("delyn_db", $con);

if (!$con)
    { 
    die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    }

if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']) )
{
    $varType = $_POST['traytype'];
}

$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['term']);    
$sql = "SELECT * FROM delyn WHERE traytype LIKE '%".$varType."%'";


$r_query = mysql_query($sql);


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){ 
echo 'ID: ' .$row['ID']; 
echo '<br /> Delyn code: ' .$row['delyncode']; 
echo '<br /> Tool Code: '.$row['toolcode'];
echo '<br /> Description: '.$row['description']; 
echo '<br /> Tray range '.$row['trayrange']; 
echo '<br /> Tray type: '.$row['traytype'];
echo '<br /> Tray size: '.$row['traysize']; 
echo '<br /> Tray height: '.$row['trayheight']; 
echo '<br /> Tray width: '.$row['traywidth']; 
echo '<br /> Tray depth: '.$row['traydepth'];
echo '<br /> Tray shape: '.$row['trayshape'];  
echo '<br /> imagename: '.$row['imagename'];
echo '<br /> Tray live: '.$row['traylive'] . ' <br /><br />';  
    }


?>
  </body>
```

Comment: what error do you get? Why do you use $_REQUEST and not $_POST['term'] ?

Comment: I don't get an error (either post or request work), just one form box seems to override the other. I want to create a search form that can take the values of all inputted to search the database.

Comment: Well, then I don't understand the 2nd form you're referring too. I'm not seeing 2 formboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use multiple inputs on the same form? Something like this:

```
<form action="form2.php" method="post"> 
          Search: <input type="text" name="term" /><br />
          Sizes: <input type="text" name="sizes" /><br />
          Select an option: <select name="dropdownselection" ><option...</option></select><br />
          ID Code: <input type="text" name="id" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

Then you can access the values in the same way you accessed value entered for the search term.
Note: you should use label tags for your labels, and use a list to layout your form.

EDIT: An option tag looks like this:

```
<option value="what is posted to the script">What is seen by the user</option>
```

EDIT: Please remove the condition surrounding the $vartype variable assignment

EDIT: Use and, not or, in your sql query, since you need both conditions to be true. If you have further questions, please open a new question, since this one is somewhat cluttered. Finally, if you feel this answer has helped you please consider accepting it.

Comment: I seem to have a bug with the dropdownbox, it doesn't return the results that are specific to the search. It just displays all of the database results.

Comment: Code:

       '<body>

  <form action="form2.php" method="post"> 
  <label for ='toolcode'>Search toolcode: </label> 
        <input type="text" name="term"/><br />
  <label for ="trayshape">Search trayshape: </label>
        <input type="text" name="term" /><br />
        <label for ="traytype"> Click traytype: </label> 
  <select name="dropdownselection" >
         <option>Rectangular</option>
            <option>Square</option>
            <option>Oval</option></select><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
  </form>'

Comment: Like this?
<form action="form2.php" method="post"> 
        <label for ="traytype"> Click traytype: </label> 
        <select name="dropdownselection" >
         <option>Choose a type</option>
         <option value="open">Open</option>
            <option value="cavitised">Cavitised</option>
        </select><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
  </form>

Comment: yes, that should work, although your select name should be "traytype".

Comment: i just can't get it working. It just displays all of the database contents. Maybe a problem with the PHP?

Comment: To only display the results of the database that have either Open of Cavitised depending on what is selected from the dropdown. Here is the PHP:

Comment: <?php
 $con = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "");
 mysql_select_db ("delyn_db", $con);
 
 if (!$con)
  { 
  die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
  }
 
 if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']) )
 {
  $varType = $_POST['traytype'];
 }
 
 $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['term']);    

$sql = "SELECT * FROM delyn WHERE traytype LIKE '%".$varType."%'";

Comment: $r_query = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){ 
echo 'ID: ' .$row['ID']; 
echo '<br /> Delyn code: ' .$row['delyncode']; 
echo '<br /> Tool Code: '.$row['toolcode'];
echo '<br /> Description: '.$row['description']; 
echo '<br /> Tray range '.$row['trayrange']; 
echo '<br /> Tray type: '.$row['traytype'];
echo '<br /> Tray size: '.$row['traysize']; 
echo '<br /> Tray height: '.$row['trayheight']; 
echo '<br /> Tray width: '.$row['traywidth']; 
echo '<br /> Tray depth: '.$row['traydepth'];

Comment: echo '<br /> Tray shape: '.$row['trayshape'];  
echo '<br /> imagename: '.$row['imagename'];
echo '<br /> Tray live: '.$row['traylive'] . ' <br /><br />';  
  }
 ?>

Comment: please edit your question, I can't make heads or tails of the code posted in your comments

Comment: You beauty, thanks so much. Fixed. Will this now work if I add more forms? Will attempt now.

Comment: Haha now with the added form boxes it goes back to displaying all of the results instead of the results that match the searches.

Comment: Would this work for using multiple dropdown boxes to find search results. I only want to display results that match both searches such as "Rectangular" "Open" tray.

$sql = "SELECT * FROM delyn WHERE traytype LIKE '%".$varType."%' OR trayshape LIKE '%".$varShape."%'";